# Google Sheet Pivot table has some bug

Tags: google-sheets, pivot-table

My pivot table from google sheets is acting all strange. The filters are not working and the data are not working. Even if I remove all the fields from the pivot table editor the table is not being affected at all. Please view the screenshot below.[The pivot table has become like static with no care of the pivot table editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gvwKy.png)

Comment: try using QUERY formula instead of buggy pivot tables

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to test under an incognito window in case any add on is affecting the Sheets, as I have similar issues with functions in the past due to that, or make a copy of it if you have not change anything of the pivot tables configuration.

If those do not work and you might think it is a bug with the way the pivot tables are working you can report it here:

https://support.google.com/docs/community

Or use the option to send feedback from the Google Sheet in the tab for "Help".